# Calling `subscribeToTopic` from a locally run cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting a permission error...

"An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions."

...when I locally run a cloud function that calls to `subscribeToTopic` and `unsubscribeToTopic`. This problem des not happen when I deploy my function to firebase.

I am using `firebase-admin` and set up firebase in my cloud function via...

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

The authentication issue only happened when calling `subscribeToTopic` and `unsubscribeToTopic`. Writing to the db from the cloud function works fine.

I was able to get around this issue by calling `admin.initializeApp` w/ a generated service account json file that I created via the firebase console.

Any ideas as to why this happened?